# SQL Server: Ambiguous sort order when collation is case-insensitive

Tags: sql-server

I have two instances of SQL Server database (the same version) on two computers. Database collation is set to **case-insensitive**. I have for example: 3 records in table that have `name` column.

*SQL Server Instance 1*

```
> select name from table1 order by name

name 
-----
Adam 
adam 
Adam
```

*SQL Server Instance 2*

```
> select name from table1 order by name

name 
-----
Adam 
Adam 
adam
```

Why sorting is ambiguous on two instaces of the same sql server database ? Why that is? What is the sort algorithm ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the collation is case insensitive then all three values are explicitly considered identical & there is no guarantee regarding the order of identical ordered rows; there can't be as there is nothing to base that decision on, there is no "natural" order.

The observed order should be considered random and relates to server internals like what data is available in the read/buffer caches, IO queues and so on.

Comment: Extra answer, eventually, to avoid different sort order on multiple instances, he may use tie-breaker, which in this case can be ASCII() function. By example, "A" and "a" doesn't have same ASCII code, and this function will be helpful

Comment: Or if it does matter he can simply stick COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS on the end